# list index is out of range for bullets in pygame

Tags: python, list, pygame

So i'm rather new to pygame, and the project i have been working with is making the old alien invasion arcade game. I know i need to clean up my pictures and display and dimensions and stuff so don't worry about that, but the problem i'm struggling with now is firing my bullets, i'm storing them in a list and then deleting them. but i come up with the error "list index out of range". this error shows up on line 50 of this code. Oh and this error only shows up while i have 2 bullets active at a time. for instance i can shoot 1 every second or two just fine, but if i rapid fire a little bit and two are moving on screen at once then i get the error   the things to really look at are on lines 42-52, 88-90,and the last 3. also any suggestions on improving the efficiency of my code is greatly appreciated

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
#keystate variables
keystate={'left':False,'right':False,'up':False,'down':False}

red=(255,0,0)
black=(0,0,0)
green=(0,255,0)
shipX=0
shipY=445
bulletsX=[]
bulletsY=[]
ship=pygame.image.load("ship.png")
ship=pygame.transform.scale(ship,(35,35))
bullet_pic=pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
bullet_pic=pygame.transform.scale(bullet_pic,(25,25))
backdrop=pygame.image.load("backdrop.png")
backdrop=pygame.transform.scale(backdrop,(640,400))

clock=pygame.time.Clock()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
screen.blit(backdrop,(0,0))

# ship movement functions
def moveship_Xneg():
    global shipX
    if shipX>0:
        shipX-=1
def moveship_Xpos():
    global shipX
    if shipX<605:
        shipX+=1
def moveship_Yneg():
    global shipY
    if shipY<445:
        shipY+=1
def moveship_Ypos():
    global shipY
    if shipY>400:
        shipY-=1

#gunfire definitions
def move_bullet():
    for bullet in range(len(bulletsX)):
        bulletsY[bullet]-=2
        screen.blit(bullet_pic,(bulletsX[bullet],bulletsY[bullet]))
        pygame.display.update()
def del_bullet():
    for bullet in range(len(bulletsX)):
#below this is line 50, realized it didn't show numbers, my bad
        if bulletsY[bullet]<=-10:
            bulletsY.remove(bulletsY[bullet])
            bulletsX.remove(bulletsX[bullet])

# ship movement changes
def start_ship(): #draws the starting position of the ship
    screen.blit(ship,(0,445))
    pygame.display.update()
def draw_newship(): #draws the new ship and updates the screen
    screen.blit(ship,(shipX,shipY))
    #screen.blit(backdrop,(shipX
    #print(shipX,shipY)
    pygame.display.update()
#def del_oldship(): #deletes the old ship

start_ship()
#Main Loop
running=True
while running:
    clock.tick(350)
    #checks keystroke events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #quits the program
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
            pygame.quit()
        #KEYDOWN CHECKS
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            #Movement variable changes
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                keystate['left']=True
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                keystate['right']=True
            if event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                keystate['down']=True
            if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                keystate['up']=True
            #Action per event
            if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
                bulletsX.append(shipX+17.5)
                bulletsY.append(shipY)
        #KEYUP CHECKS
        if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            #movement variable changes
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                keystate['left']=False
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
                keystate['right']=False
            if event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
                keystate['down']=False
            if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                keystate['up']=False
    # pygame event processing ends

    if running==True:

        #performs an action per each loop dependant on keystate variables
        if keystate['left']==True:
            #del_oldship()
            moveship_Xneg()
            draw_newship()
        if keystate['right']==True:
            #del_oldship()
            moveship_Xpos()
            draw_newship()
        if keystate['down']==True:
            #del_oldship()
            moveship_Yneg()
            draw_newship()
        if keystate['up']==True:
            #del_oldship()
            moveship_Ypos()
            draw_newship()
        if bulletsX!=[]:
            del_bullet()
            move_bullet()
        #for coord in range(len(bulletsX)):
            #print(bulletsX[coord],bulletsY[coord])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can find error in the error message. `List index out of range`

For example

```
a = [1]
a.remove(1)
>>>a[0]
`IndexError: list index out of range`
```

In your code,

```
if bulletsY[bullet] <= -10
```

This time may be no elements in `bulletsY` in the position `bullet` or list `bulletsY` may be empty.

So you can try like this

```
if bulletsY and bulletsY[bullet] <= -10
```

Hope this helps

**Updated**

Try this

```
def del_bullet():

    for bullet in range(len(bulletsX)):
#below this is line 50, realized it didn't show numbers, my bad
        try:
            if bulletsY[bullet]<=-10:
                bulletsY.remove(bulletsY[bullet])
                bulletsX.remove(bulletsX[bullet])
        except:pass
```

Comment: tried it but it didn't work, mind you when i call my del_bullet function its under the parameter that the list is not empty

Comment: Error not only list empty, but also if no element in position `bullet`

Comment: how does that work? isn't bullet just traversing each position in bulletsY? i know i have it traversing the len of the bulletsX but the length of each list is always the same. so how is bullets traversing outside the list if its only working within the len of that list? oh i made an edit with more detail too. i only get this error when i have two bullets active at a time

Comment: that's weird, I swear I tried exactly what you said, just tried it again. okay cool, just figured something out. I was misinterpreting how to use the len and then use the number to call the element. I need to subtract 1 from the len... okay that stopped the error, something else weird tho, I added in debugging statements printing the cords of my bullets. even after bullet has passed minimal y-axis and gets deleted it keeps printing that the cords are still decreasing

Comment: aha briliant that worked. sorry commented before reading ur update lol. thankyou using that also stopped the coordinate changing after it passed my minimum y so i assume its fully deleting now. thankyou very much, now onto bringing in my alien invaders